# How to make pixel operations on canvas faster in Javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas, pixel

I am writing a program to convert three equations into an image by using them to generate RGB values for each pixel on a canvas. This is the code of my first test:

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game")
const context = canvas.getContext("2d")

time = new Date()

canvas.width = 500
canvas.height = 500

for (x = 0; x < canvas.width; x++) {
  for (y = 0; y < canvas.height; y++) {
    context.fillStyle = "red"
    context.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1)
  }
}

console.log(new Date() - time)
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```

However, when I run this code it takes a few seconds to generate the canvas. I added a basic way to see how long the code takes to run, and the console appears to say it only takes 200 milliseconds. I have noo idea why it says it only takes 200 milliseconds as I do not see the canvas until a few seconds after the console log.

How can I make these pixel operations faster?

Comment: On my PC I see it almost instantly.

Comment: Interesting, I still don't think it should be too slow for my laptop though, it has an i5 and 8GB of RAM. I don't exactly want to have to have minimum specs for my website.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just using a single color, you can speed it up a bit by setting the `fillStyle` before the loop instead of setting it every iteration. That obviously won't work if you want to set different colors for different pixels, however.

You could also set the colors in an [`imageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ImageData) object, then draw it all at once with [`putImageData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/putImageData). This is significantly faster for me in both Chrome and Firefox.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById("game")
const context = canvas.getContext("2d")

time = new Date()

canvas.width = 500
canvas.height = 500

let imageData = context.createImageData(canvas.width, canvas.height)
let data = imageData.data;
let i = 0;
while (i < data.length) {
  data[i++] = 255; // Red value
  data[i++] = 0; // Green value
  data[i++] = 0; // Blue value
  data[i++] = 255; // Alpha (opacity)
}
context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0)
console.log(new Date() - time)
```

```html
<canvas id="game"></canvas>
```